# Connect AWS Managed Microsoft AD with Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, active-directory

I've created AWS Microsoft AD and need to connect it from AWS Lambda to implement the Password reset function.

> I'm going to use LDAP(389) to connect AD.  However, It worked well on
>   the Windows server which connected to AWS AD.  But when I try to
>   connect from Lambda, It's not working.  It seems like any kind of ping
>   to AD DNS IP is not working too.

Please let me know how we can access AWS AD from Lambda. 
I'm using python2.7 now. 
Thank you.

Comment: It would be good to know what you mean by "not working". Does it fail with an error message? Does it time out? If the AD servers are in a private subnet of a VPC then the Lambda function should also be in the VPC, and the AD security group should allow inbound traffic from the security group of the Lambda function.

Comment: Have you got this working?

Answer (score 0):

Try it using lambda3 library.
If your AD is in a private VPC. Build an API and then expose AD through your API and validate it.